# loop through custom post-type with two meta_keys

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, loop, metabox, meta-query

I have a custom-post-type named `my_project`. 
This post-type has two meta-boxes:

- `is_featured`
- `is_featured_position`

So essentially in my backend of the post-type I can set a **checkbox** for `is_featured` and enter a **number** for `is_featured_position`

[image]

This allows me to set a "project" to my homepage of my website.

I have a function called `get_project_list()` that should return all my "featured" projects.

```
function get_project_list( $order = 'DSC' ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'my_project',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => $order,
        'meta_key' => 'is_featured',
        // 'is_featured_position' ???
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        global $post;
        get_template_part( 'inc/project', 'item' );
    endwhile;
}
```

This already **works fine** right now.
The only question I have is how I can implement my "position" or "order" of my featured posts! All I want to do is additionally sort by the second meta_key `is_featured_position` which is a normal number.

So if I call `get_project_list( 'DSC' )` I want all featured posts returend in the order that is set inside `is_featured_position`. Just like you know it from the normal wordpress `Pages` where you can set the Order of the list-pages function.

How can I filter by this second meta_key?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `meta_query` along with `meta_(key|value|compare)` to interact with two different keys and get the order you want.

```
<?php
$q = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'my_project',
    'nopaging'       => true, // same as posts_per_page => 1,
    'order'          => $order,
    'orderby'        => 'is_featured_position', // your position key here
    'meta_key'       => 'is_featured_position', // also here, see below
    'meta_value_num' => 0, // you may want something different here
    'meta_compare'   => '>', // you may want something different here
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'is_featured',
            'copmare' => 'EXISTS', // only works in WP 3.5+
        ),
    ),
));
```

Okay, so when you use a combination of `meta_(key|value|compare)` keys along with `meta_query` some weirdness happens. WordPress uses the class `WP_Meta_Query` to parse and create metadata queries. We can take a look inside `WP_Meta_Query::parse_query_vars` to learn more.

```
/**
 * Constructs a meta query based on 'meta_*' query vars
 *
 * @since 3.2.0
 * @access public
 *
 * @param array $qv The query variables
 */
function parse_query_vars( $qv ) {
    $meta_query = array();

    // Simple query needs to be first for orderby=meta_value to work correctly
    foreach ( array( 'key', 'compare', 'type' ) as $key ) {
        if ( !empty( $qv[ "meta_$key" ] ) )
            $meta_query[0][ $key ] = $qv[ "meta_$key" ];
    }

    // WP_Query sets 'meta_value' = '' by default
    if ( isset( $qv[ 'meta_value' ] ) && '' !== $qv[ 'meta_value' ] )
        $meta_query[0]['value'] = $qv[ 'meta_value' ];

    if ( !empty( $qv['meta_query'] ) && is_array( $qv['meta_query'] ) ) {
        $meta_query = array_merge( $meta_query, $qv['meta_query'] );
    }

    $this->__construct( $meta_query );
}
```

The overall picture: `meta_(key|value|compare)` keys just become part of the `meta_query` array.

Unfortunately, WordPress only checks `meta_key` for a valid orderby, so you must include it as well as a `meta_query` with the remaining custom fields you want to use. In your case you must use the featured order field so you can use it the `orderby` argument.

The above is untested, but it should at least get you started!